# How to determine the flip-flops input in truth table

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop

I've only one simple problem about JK flip-flops. The last columns in the following table (Flip-flop inputs). How were they genereted from the other parts on the left? Does this has a relationship with the equation: J Q!+K! Q?

[image]

Comment: Could you add scheme(s) for the table, please?

Answer (score 1):

Present states A and B represent the present logic levels on the Q outputs of the two JK flip flops.

JA and KA represent the logic levels required to be applied to the J and K inputs of the 'A' flip flop to make its Q output transition from its present state to its next state upon receiving a clock pulse.

JB and KB represent the logic levels required to be applied to the J and K inputs of the 'B' flip flop to make its Q output transition from its present state to its next state upon receiving a clock pulse.

The right hand side of the table doesn't look correct, there should be some "don't cares" in there represented as crosses.

Lets take an example by looking at the first line. The Q output for the A flip flop needs to transition from 0 to 0 when a clock pulse is received. That is to say it must stay unchanged at 0. There are two combinations of JA and KA that will achieve this, JA=0 and KA=0 or JA=0 and KA=1. You will see that JA must be 0 but it doesn't matter whether KA is a 0 or a 1. Therefore KA is a "Don't Care" and the first line of the table for JA KA should read 0 X.

Being able to have some of the entries in the table as don't cares will usually enable simpler logic to be generated when implementing the Karnaugh map minimisation.

Answer (score 0):

At first: The table presents a machine which has one input (=X) an four states. The number of the current state is the binary number AB. A and B are the outputs of the two JK ffs which are used as the memory devices.  A and B are called "state variables" in the automate theory.

The machine has a four output- three input combination circuit (=gates) which generates the right inputs for the JK ffs for the wanted state transitions. The inputs of that combination circuit are A, B and X. The right hand columns show the outputs of that combination circuit. The purpose is to show what values should be applied to the J/K inputs in order to progress through the states. The Boolean equations for the outputs Ja, Ka, Jb and Kb consist A, B and X as the variables. Your own version J Q!+K! Q is nonsense.

I write one of the four Boolean equations: Ja=B. You must find the rest by yourself.

The two columns under **Next State** are the outputs, and they are derived from the columns under **Present State** and **Flip-Flop Inputs**, the actual change taking place when the active edge of the clock pulse occurs. Note: X is not the clock, it's the input of the machine.

Here's the truth table for a J-K flip flop from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#JK_latch) for comparison. The table in your question simply has two such devices. Qnext is either A or B under **Next State** and Q is either A or B under **Present State**:

[image]